# Equal delays between animations

Tags: animation, objects, graph-editor, nla-editor

I have modeled a vessel which carries tons of weight[image] I want to make a kind of building animation for the vessel all the parts drop from top smootly and sequent do you have ideas how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with each piece as a different object, that is each piece which you want to fall into place at a different time. In edit mode press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose loose parts or selection to break larger objects into smaller pieces.

Go to the end of the animation and insert a keyframe for the location of each piece. <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>I</kbd>*->Location*. now go back to the beginning of the animation and move everything up so that it is out of the camera view. Insert another keyframe, <kbd>I</kbd>*->Location*.

Now that everything is falling at the same time, go into the dopesheet and stagger the start and end times for each piece.

[image: dopesheet with staggered animation]

[image: example animation]

While it might have a learning curve to start, you may also want to consider using [animation nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDkPasOMehY).

Comment: Thanks for your help :) , but I need something like propotional edit in dopesheet I have 280 object and make those animation in a sequnce manually too hard